# How can I insert link to a component of an external webpage inside a GD dashboard?

Tags: gooddata

The user wants put a link to an external table of the webpage http://www.portalbrasil.net/incc_di.htm inside GD dashboard.

He is a power user in excel and he usually does that in Excel using DATA -> FROM WEB, which allows you to chose any part of a webpage and link to it in the spreadsheet.

How can we do it in a GD dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed any web page to GoodData Dashboard that is available via HTTPS (the URL starts with HTTPS). To do so in edit dashboard mode click "Web Content" button and paste the URL there. In your case it looks like this URL has also its HTTPS version (with some certificate warning).

You cannot import data to GoodData this way (just display the page). If you wanted to load the data from this page to your datasets, you would need to do it in CloudConnect - GET it with REST Connector and then somehow parse it from the HTML code to get raw values.